# How to decode tx data with Rust ethers.rs

Tags: rust, ethers.rs

I am trying to decode the tx data using the ethersrs crate with Rust. From the crate [source code](https://github.com/gakonst/ethers-rs/blob/40cc8cc54f7d36aa24147c937772600e5b119399/ethers-contract/src/base.rs#L174), I can see that it is possible to decode using an instance of the BaseContract type. However, I cannot see any apparent way to create this instance. Here is what I tried thus far:

```
pub fn decode(tx_input: Bytes) {
    abigen!(TestContract, "./src/web3/abi/TestContract.json");

    let contract = BaseContract::from(TestContract);

    let result = contract.decode_input(tx_input);
}
```

But I receive the following error message:

`Expected value, found struct` TestContract `constructor is not visible here due to private fields`